# How to extract specified objects from a pdf?

Tags: image-processing, text

Is it possible to extract some information from a pdf file?
I am interested in extracting the words before the squared brackets and the following word (in the image, for example, I would like to extract `A` and `s`, then `a` and `an`, and so on...)?

Many thanks for all your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: When you `Import["mypdf", "Plaintext"]`, does this text appear?

Comment: yes, the text appears. Unfortunately, my difficulties are mainly on how to extract some specific items from it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the formatting of the text seems consistent, it might suffice to partition the text by periods (`"."`) and remove newlines (`"\n"` and `"\r"`).

`text = StringSplit[StringDelete[Import["mypdf.pdf", "Plaintext"], {"\n", "\r"}], "."];`

Then, you can simply make a list of all the words you have:

`words = Flatten[StringDrop[StringCases[#, ___ ~~ "["], -2] & /@ text]`

(The `-2` is removing `[`)

I hope this works!